# Different ouput for a varchar(max) variable in print and select in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have a situation in which we declared a varchar(max) variable and assigned data after that going to insert that value in a table for further use. But when we select data we got truncated data.

```
declare @check varchar(max)

set @check = 'Calc saves your document as a file in your file system. If you open such a file in a plain text editor, you will immediately see that it is an XML document. Look at this plain file and find out where the interesting data is located. Target those elements with XSLT templates. Please note: I can only point you in the right direction, your question as such is too vague and broad for Stackoverflow.'
print @check 
select @check
```

Result :

```
Calc saves your document as a file in your file system. If you open such a file in a plain text editor, you will immediately see that it is an XML document. Look at this plain file and find out where the interesting data is located. Target those elements with XSLT templates. Please note: I can only point you in the right direction, your question as such is too vague and broad for Stackoverflow.

Calc saves your document as a file in your file system. If you open such a file in a plain text editor, you will immediately see that it is an XML document. Look at this plain file and find out where the interesting data is located. Target those elements w

(1 row(s) affected)
```

In output `select @check` is giving Truncated Result. I Want to use `select @check` to insert into table. Is any workaround?

Comment: Why would you use a select in insert?  Just insert  @check.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 5):

It's truncated because Management Studio will not necessarily output the full value to screen and has a default display width of 256 characters, which is where your cut-off occurs:

[image: SSMS Options screen]

The value of the variable itself is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry this does not reflect the data which is in the field. You can still use select to insert into the table and you would have the full contents of the field.

Run the code below to prove this

```
declare @check varchar(max)

set @check = 'Calc saves your document as a file in your file system. If you open such a file in a plain text editor, you will immediately see that it is an XML document. Look at this plain file and find out where the interesting data is located. Target those elements with XSLT templates. Please note: I can only point you in the right direction, your question as such is too vague and broad for Stackoverflow.'
print @check 
select @check 

create table #temp ([check] varchar(max))

insert into #temp
select @check 

select LEN(@check),LEN([check]) FROM #temp
```